# django-reversion revert ManyToMany fields outside admin

Tags: django, manytomanyfield, m2m, django-reversion

I am using django-reversion in my project. 
And it works good except one thing: 
I can't get previous versions of ManyToMany fields. But in django admin it is works, not in my code.
To get previous version I use following code:

> vprod = Version.objects.get_for_date(product, ondate).get_object_version().object

and it works except m2m field
where 'product' is object of Product class,

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    elements = models.ManyToManyField(Sku)

class Sku(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="SKU Name")
```

I can get `vprod.name` and it returns what I need, but when I try `vprod.elements.all()` it returns list only the current (last) version, even if the number of elements changed.

Comment: I want to receive just list of elements in defined time for my product. But code above returns only a list of elements only in last state, but name in defined time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, I think you should get the *revision* for the version; the version contains the data of the object, the revision contains versions for multiple objects. Have a look at:

> some_version.revision.version_set.all()

Concretely, I think you should use (untested):

> [
>       v for v in Version.objects.get_for_date(product, ondate).revision.version_set.all()
>       if version.content_type == ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Sku)
>   ]

Note, btw, that reversions should know that it should follow relationships. Using the [low level API](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/wiki/Low-Level-API):

> reversion.register(YourModel, follow=["your_foreign_key_field"])

Comment: > reversion.register(YourModel, follow=["your_foreign_key_field"]) I did, some_version.revision.version_set.all() as I understand do almost the same as .get_object_version()

Comment: Have you tried it? `some_version.get_object_version()` gives a 'deserialized object', `some_version.revision.version_set.all` gives a queryset with the versions of all the (followed) objects at the same time as `some_version`. The problem with versions is that they refer to model instances, not to versions, so you should get the version of a followed model instance from the `some_version.revision.version_set`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and thanks to @Webthusiast's answer I got my working code. Adapting to your example would be something like this.

Imports:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
import reversion
```

Register your models:

```
reversion.register(Sku)
reversion.register(Product, follow=['elements'])
```

And then you can iterate:

```
object = Product.objects.get(some_id)
versions = reversion.get_for_object(self.object)
for version in versions:
    elements = [v.object_version.object \
        for v in version.revision.version_set.all() \
        if v.content_type == ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Product)]
```

The documentation for this is now on Read the Docs. Refer to the '[Advanced model registration](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#advanced-model-registration)' section of the Low-level API page.